# win32gui click coordinates in BlueStacks

Tags: python, win32gui, bluestacks

I'm trying to automate a process in BlueStacks where I wait for an element to appear on the screen, and when it appears, click it. Everything works, except the clicking part, I've done a lot of research and tried different things, but I can't get it to work.

I know I can make this easily with pyautogui, but I don't want to make the program move the actual cursor, and one of the key features is that it can be run without needing to have the window on the foreground (not focusing the window).

```py
def compare_images():
    threshold = 0.80
    i = -1
    width = 0
    height = 0
    mouse_x = 0
    mouse_y = 0
    for template in templates:
        i += 1
        result_image = cv2.matchTemplate(scr, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result_image)

        width = templates[i].shape[1]
        height = templates[i].shape[0]

        if max_val > threshold:
            # Getting the mouse coordinates
            mouse_x = math.floor(max_loc[0] + width / 2)
            mouse_y = math.floor(max_loc[1] + height / 2)
            l_param = win32api.MAKELONG(mouse_x, mouse_y)
            
            # Trying to click on the coordinates
            win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, l_param)
            win32gui.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, l_param)

    print(f"Max Val: {max_val} Max Loc: {max_loc}")

    cv2.rectangle(scr, max_loc, (max_loc[0] + width, max_loc[1] + height), (0, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(scr, f"Max Loc: {max_loc}", max_loc, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(scr, (mouse_x, mouse_y), (mouse_x, mouse_y), (255, 255, 255), 10)
```